# I want to call php inserting query when i am clicking the bootstrap button

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

My problem is I am trying to call the PHP file while clicking the button on my bootstrap but it is not working for me here by I paste my code of bootstrap and PHP kindly guide me for the solution 
Thanks in advance

I am tired of changing button to form and all of these but not working I am working on PHP 7 and Bootstrap 4

````
<?php  include "includes/db.php"; ?>

<?php
// echo "<h1> Testing </h1>";
// $db = mysql_select_db("cateory", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
function(){
        if (isset($POST['submit'])){
          // $connect=mysqli_query($connection,)
          $cat_title=$POST['cat_title'];
          if($cat_title==""||empty($cat_title)){
            echo "The field should not empty";

          }
          else{
            $query="INSERT INTO category (cat_title)";
            $query .=" VALUE ('{$cat_title}')";
            $create_category_query = mysqli_query ($connection,$query);
            if(!$create_category_query){
              die ('QUERY FAILED'.mysqli_error($connection));
            }
          }
         }
        }
        ?>```
  <!-- ADD CATEGORY MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addCategoryModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-success text-white">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Add Category</h5>
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span>&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
````

````
    <?php insert_categories();  ?>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal">Save Changes</button>```

    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
````

Comment: Please be aware that your code is **vulnerable** to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). **Never** use `$_POST` (or equivalent variables) directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding to variables. Also ensure the user only has the [**required privileges**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: I think your isset condition not working. use $_POST instead of $post

Answer (score 0):

Do change your code like:

````
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit']) ) {
    // $connect=mysqli_query($connection,)
    $cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];

    if($cat_title==""||empty($cat_title)){
        echo "The field should not empty";
    } else {
        $query="INSERT INTO category (cat_title)";
        $query .= " VALUE ('{$cat_title}')";
        $create_category_query = mysqli_query ($connection,$query);

        if(!$create_category_query){
            die ('QUERY FAILED'.mysqli_error($connection));
        }
    }
}
?>
<!-- ADD CATEGORY MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addCategoryModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-success text-white">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add Category</h5>
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span>&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <?php insert_categories();  ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal">Save Changes</button>```
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
````

Problems with your code:

- Your HTML formatting itself is wrong. you have broken your form tag with div of `modal-body`. You have to reconsider your HTML design.
- No need to wrap PHP code in a function with no name.
  You just have to use the code only.
- You have named your input as `title` while saving/checking data as `cat_title`.
- Check your whole codebase again.